# Random variables with zero mean and expectation of product equal zero

Tags: random-variables, expected-value, conditional-expectation, independence

If i have two random variables X and Y such that E[X]=0 and E[Y]=0 and E[XY]=0

Can I conclude that E[X|Y]=0?
And can I conclude that they are independant?

Comment: NO, for both. Take $X \sim N(0,1)$ and $Y=X$ if $|X| \leq a$, $-X$ if $|X| >a$. Choose $a$ appropriately.

Comment: thank u @KaviRamaMurthy